# Why does POST 'backend endpoint' net::ERR_FAILED is occured?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-post, fetch-api

First error:

> POST http://62.113.97.194:8000/api/v1/users/token net::ERR_FAILED

```
  const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "backend endpoint",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setAuthTokens(data);
        setUser(jwt(data.access));
        localStorage.setItem("authTokens", JSON.stringify(data));
        navigate("/");
      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        console.error("Login failed:", errorData);
        alert(`Login failed: ${errorData.message}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An unexpected error occurred during login:", error);
      alert(`An unexpected error occurred: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };
```

```
 const handleTokenRequest = async () => {
    try {
      if (!otp) {
        console.error(
          "Verification code is empty. Please provide a valid code."
        );
        return;
      }

      const response = await fetch(
        "backend endpoint",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: 1,
            password: 1,
            phone: formData.phoneNumber,
            verification_code: otp,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const accessToken = responseData.access;
        const refreshToken = responseData.refresh;

        // Log tokens in the console
        console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);
        console.log("Refresh Token:", refreshToken);

        loginUser(accessToken, refreshToken);

        // Additional logic, such as redirecting the user or showing a success message
      } else {
        console.error("Token request failed. Something went wrong!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during token request:", error);

      if (error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
        console.error("Invalid verification code or user not found");
      }
    }
  };
```

Second error:

> An unexpected error occurred during login: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at loginUser (AuthContext.jsx:15:30)
> at handleTokenRequest (index.jsx:159:9)

[image: screenshots from network]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to check with other developers in different groups, but unfortunately I did not receive an answer to my question, I also tried to fix the issue by myself but i couldn't, I also tried to find out the answer to my question from AI, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's potential issues:

1. From image your API endpoint seems correct.
2. Your try catch statements Don't have any throw Error. I suggest adding those inside try. It might give you the idea why error happened.

```
 throw new Error("Error happened", error);
```

3. fetch() will only reject a promise if the user is offline, or some unlikely networking error occurs, such a DNS lookup failure. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful),

So after fetch you should add something like that

```
if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Error happened");
    }
```